# Use GWT+Eclipse to develop and deploy JSR-168 portlets

Tags: eclipse, gwt, portlet, liferay, jsr168

I have a GWT app that I want to build as a Portlet.
I have already done that with [Liferay](http://liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/How+to+build+a+GWT+Portlet+in+Liferay) but the portlet generated (.war file) cannot be deployed into Apache Pluto.

I would like to know if anybody has some HOWTO info about how to build JSR-168 portlets (with GWT and Eclipse) that can be deployed in any JSR-168 compliant portal. I'm not sure if this is possible though.

I've already read the oficial documentation offered by [Pluto](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/v11/deploying.html) and I  really need something more detailed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What specifically makes it not able to be deployed in a standard container?

I've written GWT apps into pluto based portals a few times and haven't had too many issues outside of communicating data into the app.  In short, I created a standard JSP portlet that loaded the GWT javascript files that get generated during compile and loaded the app into a div panel in the JSP page for the portlet.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home).  It uses GWT for the UI but works on the server side and can be easily embedded as a portlet.  I know that works [extremely well for Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+Vaadin+Applications+as+Liferay+Portlets) as I've personally written Vaadin (GWT) apps and deployed them as portlets in liferay.  Additionally, Vaadin [states here](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.portal.html) that it will support JSR-168 compliant portals like Pluto.